# LINQ - Grouping objects with count of type

Tags: linq, grouping, aggregate

I have a collection of objects that each defined by a particular "group". How can I write a LINQ query to produce a count of each object grouped by "group".

As an example, lets say I have the following classes;

```
public class Release 
{
     int ReleaseNumber; 

     public ReleaseDetails[] details;

}

public class ReleaseDetails
{
    string Group;

    // other details omitted
}
```

For a given release, I'd like to be able to produce output like;

```
Release number 1 contains the following details;
 - 17 records in Group A
 - 12 records in Group B
 - 6 records in Group C
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
var q = from d in r.Details
            group d by d.Group into counts
            select new { Count = counts.Count(), Group = counts.Key };
```

Full example:

```
        Release r = new Release
        {
            ReleaseNumber = 1
            ,
            Details = new ReleaseDetails[]
            {
                new ReleaseDetails { Group = "a"},
                new ReleaseDetails { Group = "a"},
                new ReleaseDetails { Group = "b"},
                new ReleaseDetails { Group = "c"},
                new ReleaseDetails { Group = "d"},
                new ReleaseDetails { Group = "d"},
                new ReleaseDetails { Group = "e"},

            }
        };

        var q = from d in r.Details
                group d by d.Group into counts
                select new { Count = counts.Count(), Group = counts.Key };

        foreach (var count in q)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Group {0}: {1}", count.Group, count.Count);
        }
```

Comment: Awesome. Just what I was after. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
    public class ReleaseDetails
    {
        public string Group { get; set; }
        public ReleaseDetails() {}
        public ReleaseDetails(string grp){Group = grp;}
    }

            var qry = new Release();
            qry.details = new List<ReleaseDetails>();
            qry.details.Add(new ReleaseDetails("A"));
            qry.details.Add(new ReleaseDetails("A"));
            qry.details.Add(new ReleaseDetails("B"));
            qry.details.Add(new ReleaseDetails("C"));
            qry.details.Add(new ReleaseDetails("C"));
            qry.details.Add(new ReleaseDetails("B"));


 var result = from x in qry.details
                group x by x.Group into g
                select new 
                { 
                    Count = g.Count(), 
                    Group = g.Key 
                };

//Or using Labmda
var result1 = qry.details.GroupBy(x => x.Group).Select(g => new { Count = g.Count(), Group = g.Key });
```

Comment: Hmmm, like faesters example, you actually need to provide the Group property within ReleaseDetails before you attempt to group by it in the linq query. Other than that, it looks like you came up with almost the exact same as faester.

Comment: Sorry i did not copy the ReleaseDetails ctor where i assign Group.The code assumes it was included in "other details omitted".

Comment: I edited the answer to include ctor and lambda way of doing grouping.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the edit and alternative example using Lambda. I appreciate you taking the time to make the adjustments. +1